# How to `diff` files to create a "common" file?

Tags: css, bash, shell, diff, zsh

I have a slew of CSS files to go through where someone just grunted through making alterations to various core stylesheets on a number of subsites.  Obviously if the original developer had had some foresight they would have just included a master stylesheet and overridden the necessary elements…

I first started off with `comm` thinking that it might do the trick, but quickly found that it needed to receive a sorted input file.

I then switched over to `diff` and have gotten down to the following through some reading and [research](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1105/47012):

```
diff --unchanged-group-format="@@ %dn,%df%c'\012'%<" --old-group-format='' --new-group-format='' --changed-group-format='' file_1.css file_2.css
```

The previous obviously is almost there, but:

**A)** I need to grep out the `@@` lines (which should be fine, right? At first glance this appears right, but does `diff` throw in any other unexpected lines that need to be yanked?) and then

**B)** I need to create two more files that first is the leftover unique lines from file_1.css and then the leftover unique lines of file_2.css.

Obviously the first "in common" file will go into an include folder and then be included into the two latter created files as a `@import url("common.css");`

I am thinking that the following simple alteration will create the latter two files to which I'm referring:

```
diff --unchanged-group-format='' --old-group-format="@@ %dn,%df%c'\012'%<" --new-group-format='' --changed-group-format='' file_1.css file_2.css

diff --unchanged-group-format='' --old-group-format='' --new-group-format="@@ %dn,%df%c'\012'%<" file_1.css file_2.css
```

### Sample files:

> file 1: https://gist.github.com/c13843972c47b5037704
>
> file 2: https://gist.github.com/fff39eae386e8969dc10

So for example, upon executing a test of the following:

```
diff --unchanged-group-format="@@ %dn,%df%c'\012'%<" --old-group-format='' --new-group-format=''   --changed-group-format='' file_1.css file_2.css | egrep -v "^@@\d*" > common.css

diff --unchanged-group-format='' --old-group-format="@@ %dn,%df%c'\012'%<" --new-group-format=''   --changed-group-format='' file_1.css file_2.css | egrep -v "^@@\d*" > old.css
```

And then searching for `body` with `egrep "^body" *css`, it yielded only a body in `common.css` and none in `old.css`, whereas it showed that there were two different entries in `file_1.css` and `file_2.css`.  So obviously this methodology is flawed.

***How would one about creating these two files that would ultimately become the common include and the override files?***

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input files and your expected output.

Comment: @anubhava there you go.

Comment: Might not help much, but you could perhaps combine those files first and then use something like http://zamez.org/factorcss ?

Comment: Interesting @stephenhay, however the system keeps throwing errors on gist raw links.  Odd as it ends in css as it says it should, but certainly lends to a lack of trust in the results.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. Hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@ylluminate, you have a couple of options:

1. use BeyondCompare to visually verify the differences. It does a fantastic job comparing similar files. It allows saving common lines/left only lines/right only lines. Only downside is it is interactive and if you have a lot of files, will take some time. On the positive side, it looks like you want to build trust first by testing it out a few times.
2. Add formatting text for --changed-group-format and capture modified code (and the old code as your command does it now). You need to run one more comparison to get what is in new code but not in old code. Downside here is the validation is going to be hard.
3. Saving all the lines in a database table and comparing columns is another option. Take care to store old and new line numbers. Downsides are the data lines need to be unique, blank lines will be chopped off.

I would go with option 1 if i have less than 50 files.

Hope this helps.

PS: I am not associated with BeyondCompare in any way. just a happy user of the software